# Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 18485292 byte allocation with 15229320 free bytes and 14MB until OOM"

Tags: java, android

I have this error in one activity a bout out of memory :

> Process: com.moments.hamza.babytalk, PID: 16463
>                                                                               java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 18485292 byte allocation with 15230424 free bytes and 14MB until OOM
>                                                                                   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:747)
>                                                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:568)
>                                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
>                                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3747)
>                                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
>                                                                                   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:151)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:140)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1030)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
>                                                                                   at com.moments.hamza.babytalk.Level_2.onCreate(Level_2.java:49)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)

the xml layout file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.moments.hamza.babytalk.Level_2"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/v_f_level2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_aid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_a"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_bid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_b"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_cid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_c"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_did"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_d"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_eid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_e"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_fid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_f"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_gid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_g"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_hid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_h"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_iid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_i"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_jid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_j"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_kid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_k"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_lid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_l"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_mid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_m"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_nid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_n"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_oid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_o"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_pid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_p"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_qid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_q"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_rid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_r"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_sid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_s"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_tid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_t"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_uid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_u"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_vid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_v"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_wid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_w"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_xid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_x"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_yid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_y"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/letter_zid"
            android:src="@drawable/letter_z"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/a_letter" />

    </ViewFlipper>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/next_level_2"
        android:src="@drawable/next"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/back_level_2"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/next_level_2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the main code for level_2 is :

```
public class Level_2 extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView back_level_2;
private ImageView next_level_2;

private ImageView letteraj;
private ImageView letterbj;
private ImageView lettercj;
private ImageView letterdj;
private ImageView letterej;
private ImageView letterfj;
private ImageView lettergj;
private ImageView letterhj;
private ImageView letterij;
private ImageView letterjj;
private ImageView letterkj;
private ImageView letterlj;
private ImageView lettermj;
private ImageView letternj;
private ImageView letteroj;
private ImageView letterpj;
private ImageView letterqj;
private ImageView letterrj;
private ImageView lettersj;
private ImageView lettertj;
private ImageView letteruj;
private ImageView lettervj;
private ImageView letterwj;
private ImageView letterxj;
private ImageView letteryj;
private ImageView letterzj;

private ViewFlipper v_f_level2j;
private TextToSpeech t1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_2);

    v_f_level2j = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.v_f_level2);

    back_level_2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next_level_2);
    next_level_2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_level_2);

    letteraj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_aid);
    letterbj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_bid);
    lettercj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_cid);
    letterdj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_did);
    letterej=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_eid);
    letterfj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_fid);
    lettergj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_gid);
    letterhj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_hid);
    letterij=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_iid);
    letterjj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_jid);
    letterkj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_kid);
    letterlj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_lid);
    lettermj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_mid);
    letternj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_nid);
    letteroj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_oid);
    letterpj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_pid);
    letterqj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_qid);
    letterrj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_rid);
    lettersj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_sid);
    lettertj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_tid);
    letteruj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_uid);
    lettervj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_vid);
    letterwj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_wid);
    letterxj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_xid);
    letteryj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_yid);
    letterzj=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter_zid);

    t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

            }
        }
    });
    letteraj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="A";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterbj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="B";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    lettercj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="C";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterdj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="D";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterej.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="E";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterfj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="F";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    lettergj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="G";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterhj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="H";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterij.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="I";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterjj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="J";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterkj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="K";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterlj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="L";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    lettermj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="M";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letternj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="N";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letteroj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="O";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterpj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="P";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterqj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="Q";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterrj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="R";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    lettersj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="S";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    lettertj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="T";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letteruj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="U";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    lettervj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="V";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterwj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="W";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterxj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="X";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letteryj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="Y";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});
    letterzj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak ="Z";
            t1.setSpeechRate((float) 1);
            t1.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}});





    next_level_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v_f_level2j.showNext();
        }

    });


    back_level_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v_f_level2j.showPrevious();
        }

    });

}
}
```

can you please help me  ?

Comment: Most likely you have an image which is using too much memory. Note: image are uncompressed in memory so they are much bigger than their compressed size.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't understand ( entire stack trace )

Comment: @PeterLawrey How I can know which one ?

Comment: @HamzahAbdullah The lines below java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 18485292 byte allocation with 15229320 free bytes and 14MB until OOM in the stacktrace

Comment: You can see which line the error is thrown on in the stack trace.

Comment: @GauravVashisth many thanks Done

Comment: As Peter said, may be you are using very large images. Or It may be happening due to large number of ImageViews (28) in your layout.

Comment: @GauravVashisth actually I don't use large size image size of all these is : 169 KB , but maybe the large number the problem don't know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One or more of your `ImageView` widgets is pointing to a resource that is approximately 2150 x 2150 pixels. This is much too large. Use smaller images.

> the largest size is : 28KB

That is the size **on disk**, which is not that useful.

> the largest dimension is 660X778

Then my guess is that you put the images in `res/drawable/`, and you are testing on a device or emulator with `-xxhdpi` density. `res/drawable/` is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`, and the drawables there are for medium-density screens. When you load them on an `-xxhdpi` density environment, those images will be scaled by a factor of 3 on each axis, to keep the image the same physical size as it would be on an `-mdpi` device.

Comment: Just for curiosity, from where did you caught this?

Comment: the largest size is : 28KB and the largest dimension is 660X778

Comment: @PrerakSola: The stack trace shows the error is coming from getting a drawable resource for an `ImageView`. The image takes up 18485292 bytes / 4 bytes/pixel = 4621323 pixels. If this image were square, that would be ~2150 on a side. Of course, the image might not be square.

Comment: That's some smart calculation.. :)

Comment: @CommonsWare I am making an app that does photo editing. So for showing the user, how their image looks after editing, I am using smaller image, but for storing it on cloud, I am re-applying the effects on the actual sized image and getting an OOM. Do you think it would be a better idea to apply the edits on a JPEG compressed version rather than the actual size. How much of a benefit would it be? I am getting an OOM for allocating approx 30 MB RAM for an int array.

Comment: @Raymond232: "Do you think it would be a better idea to apply the edits on a JPEG compressed version rather than the actual size" -- a `Bitmap` is not a JPEG compressed version, so I am not certain what you mean by this. If you can apply your effects on a streaming basis, reading in some small number of JPEG bytes and writing them back out after changes, that would be great from a memory-management standpoint. "I am getting an OOM for allocating approx 30 MB RAM for an int array" -- that is not at all surprising.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can apply some filters, like saturation, contrast, brightness etc on a pixel by pixel basis, so for that your suggestion would work fine. But I have a few other filters like cartoonification and vignettifying which take the entire image (currently in bitmap) as input and do opencv operations on them. I cannot feed into those operations a subset of pixels. Do you have any idea how do other apps like instagram deal with such scenarios, what with 4K images coming in these days?

Comment: @Raymond232: I would assume that they use the NDK. Partially, that would be for speed. Partially, that would be for memory allocation, as `malloc()` (and things layered atop of it) do not count against your heap limit.

Comment: @CommonsWare,  Hmm, let me see how to make use of that. You mean, the memory that my open CV code (in C++) allocates using new and malloc would not give me an OOM? But there must be a runtime limit on that as well too, right?

Comment: @Raymond232: "But there must be a runtime limit on that as well too, right?" -- there is a hardware limit, in terms of the amount of system RAM on the device. I am not aware of any limits other than that for NDK code.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for that mate. Really appreciated your quick response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174950/discussion-between-raymond-232-and-commonsware).